# htaccess rewritebase doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I am making a website from scratch in clean PHP (no frameworks), and I am struggling with .htaccess rewriting. I am using WAMP, I have mod_rewrite turned on, and I have this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ index.php?mod=Pages&id=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

"website" is the project folder, the base folder for the website. However, when I try this URL rewrite, instead of the browser going to

> localhost/website/index.php?mod=Pages&id=X

it goes to

> localhost/index.php?mod=Pages&id=X

skipping the root folder of the project. I have tried

```
RewriteBase /
```

as well, but I get the same result...

Comment: Do you have any other rules? where is the htaccess file? did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Also what's the reason of using `R=301` above?

Comment: I have no other rules, just this one. The htaccess file is in the root of the website. I have tried clearing my browser's cache, I have also tried using several different browsers, still the same thing happens. As for R=301, I tried both with that, and without it (just with[L]), and it's still the same.